# Question about "immediate" observation about finitely presentable objects

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

The following is an excerpt from volume II of Borceux:

[image]

Here $F$ is the left adjoint to the forgetful functor $U:\mathsf{Mod}_\mathcal{T}\longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$. I'm confused and can't manage to actually show the "immediate" fact. If we take the "adjoints" of $u,v$ then we lose the coequalizer diagram..
Step-by-step assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: The quotient of a congruence is literally a quotient in the classical sense, and the kernel pair of any homomorphism is a congruence. So the coequaliser has to be the quotient by the smallest congruence. Think concretely!

Comment: @ZhenLin I tried to follow your reasoning, but I couldn't. Could you be a little more detailed? Does this rely on the fact equivalence relations are effective?

Comment: It follows that equivalence relations are effective.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't understand how you deduced the coequaliser has to be the quotient by the smallest congruence. The kernel pair is always a congruence in any category.

Comment: Why should $u,v$ be a kernel pair?

Comment: Any coequaliser is always the coequaliser of its kernel pair. I'm not assuming anything about the original parallel pair.